# How to add python to PATH using batch file on Windows

Tags: python, batch-file, installation, path

I want to install python3.XX using a .bat file.

```
echo - Installing Python...
start /W "" "python-3.11.1-amd64.exe"
del python-3.10.11 /q

echo - Adding to PATH...
set "PythonFolder=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310-32"
echo %PythonFolder%
setx path "%path%=%path%;%PythonFolder%"
set "PythonScriptsFolder=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Scripts"
echo %PythonScriptsFolder%
setx path "%path%=%path%;%PythonScriptsFolder%"

pause
```

for example l'm using  python-3.11.1-amd64.exe.

by executing this code i don't find the folders i 've added, even if the response i have is like this:

> ram Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Co;C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Scripts"
>
> AVVISO: i dati salvati sono stati troncati a una lunghezza di 1024 caratteri.
>
> OPERAZIONE RIUSCITA: valore specificato salvato.

And even if I reboot when I type `python --version`, I get an error message stating that python doesn't exist.

Is there a better way?

```
echo - Installing Python...
start /W "" "python-3.11.1-amd64.exe"
del python-3.10.11 /q

echo - Adding to PATH...
set "PythonFolder=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310-32"
echo %PythonFolder%
setx path "%path%=%path%;%PythonFolder%"
set "PythonScriptsFolder=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Scripts"
echo %PythonScriptsFolder%
setx path "%path%=%path%;%PythonScriptsFolder%"

pause
```

Comment: **Do not ever use `setx.exe` to add to the `%PATH%` environment variable**. That variable is different from all of the others in that it is a dynamic variable consisting of all of the values from both the System and User environments. If you have used it like that already, you will have corrupted your User PATH by prepending everything from your System PATH to it. As a result you will subsequently have multiple duplicates which will be evident if you open a new Command Prompt window and type `PATH`. You should obviously fix that before continuing further.

Comment: If I was going to put that abomination onto a Windows PC, I would use the built-in installation options `PrependPath=1` or preferably `AppendPath=1`, _(to match your above example)_. I would also consider including the `/quiet` or possibly the ``SimpleInstall=1`` option too. More installation option information is available directly from the [Software Developer](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html).

Comment: Also, you should not need the `Start` command. Once the installer has completed, the next command, (in this case your installer deletion command), should run.

Comment: Additionally your file is not named `python-3.10.11` so using `del python-3.10.11 /q` is not going to delete `python-3.11.1-amd64.exe`, and even with the correct filename, the `/q` option is not needed either. You should be using just `Del "python-3.11.1-amd64.exe"`, or depending upon circumstances `Del /A /F "python-3.11.1-amd64.exe"`. If you wanted to delete possibly multiple versions of an earlier installer, using a wildcard, you could then use the `/Q` option. For example, `Del /A /F /Q "python-3.10*"`.